# Logging module not writing to file

Tags: python, windows, powershell, logging

I'm using `logging` module, and I've passed in the same parameters that I have on other jobs that are currently working:

```
import logging
from inst_config import config3

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s',
    filename=config3.GET_LOGFILE(config3.REQUESTS_USAGE_LOGFILE))
logging.warning('This should go in the file.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.info('Starting unload.')
```

Using this method to create the filename:

```
REQUESTS_USAGE_LOGFILE = r'C:\RunLogs\Requests_Usage\requests_usage_runlog_{}.txt'.format(
        CUR_MONTH)
def GET_LOGFILE(logfile):
    """Truncates file and returns."""
    with open(logfile, 'w'):
        pass
    return logfile
```

When I run it, however, it is creating the file, and then still outputting the logging info to the console.  I'm running in `Powershell`.

Just tried putting it inside the main statement like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s',
    filename=config3.GET_LOGFILE(config3.REQUESTS_USAGE_LOGFILE))

    logging.warning('This should go in the file.')
```

Still no luck.

Comment: can you show us the code you're usign to write to the log file?

Comment: Have you created the log file before the `if __name__ == '__main__':` runs? I mean... if you run your program, it'll know where's the log file? Can you make a test by putting the  `logging.basicConfig()` and creating the log file inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block?

Comment: Sure I'll try that.  EDIT:  I placed it inside the main statement, and still printing to the console:/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try running this snippet in your main file.

```
import logging 
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO, 
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s',
    filename='filename.txt')  # pass explicit filename here 
logger = logging.get_logger()  # get the root logger
logger.warning('This should go in the file.')
print logger.handlers   # you should have one FileHandler object
```

Comment: I didn't include my imports, but it is indeed loaded at the top of the file.  I've added my imports to the OP.

Comment: Still didn't work.  It's not creating the file since it's never writing to it.  Could the problem be powershell?  The weird thing is I have other jobs with the exact same configuration that run without a hitch.

Comment: You say here that _it's not creating the file_, but in the main post you say _When I run it, however, it is creating the file_.  Which is it?

Comment: That led me to the solution @Forge, for some reason it defaulted to a streaming handler this time around, so I added a `fileHandler`.

Answer (score 35):

I add the following lines before the `logging.basicConfig()` and it worked for me.

```
for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
```

Comment: @yue dong - Can you explain why this solved the problem (p.s. - it solved for me as well) ?

Comment: @yue dong, I'm second. Could you explain, why removing handlers from root logger helps?

Comment: It works, but what kind of dark magic is in there?

Comment: Thanks, but this behavior is more like a logging module bug than anything?

Comment: This didn't work for me and instead broke my code :/

Comment: So I have a program that often crashed with a segfault (due to c++ externals), and I need to do this. I suspect it's something that's needed when the code doesn't exit cleanly or with a regular python error.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Forge's answer on using `logging.basicConfig()`, as of Python 3.8 a parameter to basicConfig() got added. To [quote the docs](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1912):

```
"""
This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers 
configured, unless the keyword argument *force* is set to ``True``.
...
force     If this keyword  is specified as true, any existing handlers
          attached to the root logger are removed and closed, before
          carrying out the configuration as specified by the other
          arguments.
"""
```

This is why yue dong's answer to remove all handlers has worked for some as well as Alexander's answer to reset logger.handlers to [].

Debugging `logger.handlers` (as Forge's answer suggests) led me to see a single `StreamHandler` there (so basicConfig() did nothing for me until I used `force=True` as parameter).

Hope that helps in addition to all the other answers here too!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 'root' logger which is by default has name "", than you can do this trick:

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)    
logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger.handlers = []
```

In addition you may want to specify logging level as in code above, this level will persist for all descendant loggers.

If instead, you specified particular logger, than do

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my_service')
logger.handlers = []
fh = logging.FileHandler(log_path)
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# create console handler
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.info('service started')
```

The above code will create new logger 'my_service'. In case that logger has been already created it clears all handles. That it adds handles for writing in specified file and console. [See official documentation as well](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html).

You can also use hierarchical loggers. It is done directly.

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my_service.update')
logger.info('updated successfully')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="logs.log", filemode="w", format="%(asctime)s %(message)s", level=0, force=True)

for i in range(2):
    print(f"hello {i}")
    logging.info(f"hello {i}")
```

set level=0, filemode="a" or "w". if you set filemode w then it will overwrite previous logs but if you want to append logs, you must use filemode="a".