# QGIS - Python - Logging output log file

Tags: python, logging, qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to output a log file while I run my process in QGIS python. The script I used did not output any log file.

I tried the script below

```
import logging
formatter = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logfilename=r'c:\temp\example.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=logfilename, level=logging.INFO, format=formatter)
logging.info("This logging info text goes into the file")
logging.debug("This logging debug text goes into the file as well")
```

Expecting a log file to be save in c:\temp\

Comment: This could be a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898160/logging-module-not-writing-to-file?rq=1. See if this helps you out.

Comment: I tried and got an error below -
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'get_logger'

Comment: Try `logging.getLogger` instead of `logging.get_logger`. Given how the `print` statement was defined, I believe the SO solution is python 2x compatible whereas `getLogger` is python 3x compatible.

Comment: No error. But no output file also. I just run the script with an empty file. The print output - [<StreamHandler (NOTSET)>]